# Youtube crash when press uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiwebview, youtube, crash

I have some problem with Youtube video in `uiwebView`. When I tried to play a video, the application is crashed. But no error description. This is only the case in *iOS 7*. In iOS 6 it works fine.
I create test app with this code its work too. But in my app is not playing. 
Where there may be an error? anyone has ideas?

here is my *webView*:

```
NSString *embedHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html>\
                           <head>\
                           <style type=\"text/css\">\
                           body {background-color: transparent;}\
                           </style>\
                           </head>\
                           <body style=\"margin:0\">\
                           <iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\"></iframe>\
                           </body>\
                           </html>", @"l3Iwh5hqbyE", self.testView.bounds.size.width-3, self.testView.bounds.size.height];

    [self.testView loadHTMLString:embedHtml baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Problem in my app settings. Also not work MPMoviePlayerViewController and XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController. All perfectly work in another     projects.

Comment: so what the solution? what did you change in the settings?

Comment: I have a category of UIButton, who used in current UIView controller.
Method "init" of this category confict with UIWebView. After deleting this, I was happy.